# TEXTJOIN Excel formula without implicit intersection

Tags: excel, jet

I'm writing an Excel formula to join a series of cells into on, with the pipe as a separator. But the contents of the resulting cell should only show if another parameter exists.

```
=TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,IF(Company!$E$4:$E$30="Late",Company!$B$4:$B$30,""))
```

So assuming companies A, B, C and D, and only B and D are late, the result will be `B|D`.
The companies are refreshed via a Jet Report (for Microsoft Dynamics 365 Business Central), and once the data has refreshed, the TEXTJOIN formula has been amended using the [implicit intersection](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/implicit-intersection-operator-ce3be07b-0101-4450-a24e-c1c999be2b34) symbol, @:

```
=TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,IF(@Company!$E$4:$E$30="Late",@Company!$B$4:$B$30,""))
```

This causes the TEXTJOIN to return zero responses (in the example above, no company shows  ).
Does anyone know if it's possible to stop Excel/Jet converting this clearly non-Jet formula into an implicit intersection, or is there a better way to display the combined entries into a single cell?

Thanks in advance

Comment: try this formula instead: `=TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,FILTER(Company!$B$4:$B$30,Company!$E$4:$E$30="Late",""))`

Comment: @ScottCraner - thank you so much. That is working an absolute treat. I have edited this for a few other forumulae I need, too, but it seems to be adding ```@``` into nested ```OR()``` functions. As for this question, though, your response is perfect. I'll play about with my other issues and will post a new question if needed. Thanks again.